# How to set d3.js ticks dynamically

Tags: d3.js

I have a grouped bar chart that is dynamic and can be reloaded with new data at any point. And it works as expected most of the time.

My problem  is that on the xAxis when the value of my data is 1 the xAxis shows  1 for each  tick instead of 0 1  2 3 4 5 with a bar from 0 to one. The bar goes all the way across the chart when this happens.

if I set xAxis.ticks to 1 the ticks on the chart are fine (0 and 1) but then if my value goes above 1 there are only 2 ticks on the chart. (0 to 15)  Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: It's very hard to help you without seeing any code...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just adding 5 to the x domain.

var formatxAxis = d3.format('.0f');

```
            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(x)
                .orient("bottom")
                //.tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));
                .ticks(5)
                .tickFormat(formatxAxis);

            y0.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.groupLabel; }));
            y1.domain(subgroupLabels).rangeRoundBands([0, y0.rangeBand()]);
            x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
                return d3.max(d.subgroups, function (d) {

                    var v; 

                    d.value > 4 ? v = d.value : v = 5  
                    return v;
                });
            })]);
```